# Nesting Media Queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, retina-display

By default I want to give my body element a green border. On a device that supports retina display I want to check for size first. On an ipad I want to give my body a red border and on an iphone I want to give it a blue border. But nesting media queries like so doesn't work:

```
body { border: 1px solid green; }

@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
   @media (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 320px) {
      body { border: 1px solid red; }
   }
   @media (max-width: 320px) {
      body { border: 1px solid blue; }
   }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is here, but if you want to know whether your CSS is validation you can check it with the W3C CSS Validation Tool. I have tried it with nested media queries and it didn't like it... You can access the tool here: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No. You need to use the `and` operator and write that as two queries. You can, however, do this in SCSS, which will compile to CSS, but it will combine them by unfolding them and using the `and` operator.

This is a common problem, and once I first wrote LESS or SCSS, I didn't ever want to go back to writing this long-hand.

Long-handed CSS:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 320px),
                  (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 320px) {
  body {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 320px),
                  (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 320px) {
  body {
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
}
```

Nesting queries may work, but support varies across browsers.

Comment: can you please provide an example doing it the long hand way. I can't use any CSS precompilers at the company I work, at least not for this current project.

Comment: You can nest them, but flattening them is the only way to ensure cross-browser validity.

Comment: In fact looking at the original logic, that probably needs to be unwound into four rules not two in order to be the same. SCSS is so much easier.

Comment: I've corrected the query to ensure it's the same as your orginal (in fact I just ran it through LESS for ease. I'd be surprised if you couldn't make the case for LESS on your project citing exactly this example. I don't tend to use browser compilation, OR server compilation, I just build the CSS files as I go along. There are a number of command line methods for this or there are editor plugins that allow you to write LESS and spit out CSS. I find it hard to imagine any project would prevent you from doing that. There are even online tools. eg. http://lesstester.com/

Answer (score 14):

## In 2020, yes!

Actually the accepted answer has been outdated for a long time now. I'm not even sure if it was technically correct even at the time of posting. Firefox has supported nesting since 2012 and Chrome since 2013 ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#browser_compatibility:%7E:text=Nested%20media%20queries)).

**You should expect support from all major browsers now**, of course with the usual exception of IE.

You can test it using the following HTML and CSS. Just open up dev panel in your browser and vary your viewport width.

```css
#abc {
  background: green;
}
/* width < 801px */
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #abc#abc {
    background: red;
  }
  /* 500px < width < 801px */
  @media (min-width: 500px) {
    #abc#abc#abc {
      background: yellow;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="abc">Example text</div>
```

Alternatively, check out [this codepen](https://codepen.io/cyqsimon/pen/gOpzmBe).