# How to ignoring media queries with css

Tags: css

Hey I am wondering if lets say you have a media query in one css for mobile and the print css needs to ignore that particular media query. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways you could do that.

Either you create a stylesheet with the style that will be print (so different from the actual style of your page) and link it to your html file like this for example:

`<link rel="stylesheet" **media="print"** href="print.css" type="text/css" />`

Or below your media query, you add a media query specific for printer (so it will be applied only for printed page) like this:

`@media **print** {
  //your code
}`

Let me know if it helped or if you were thinking about something else.

Comment: No sorry it doesn't work :( Lets say I have a print query and a width query on the same page at the bottom, and I want the print query to ignore the width query.

Comment: Currently your code does not do that

Answer (score 3):

Ok then maybe you could give this a try:

With CSS3 (not CSS2.1) it seems that you can nest @media rules, so do:

`@media not print {
    @media (max-width:...px) {
        //your code
    }
}`

Comment: n/p, I'm happy it helped ;)

Comment: Sorry I was going to say something. It worked but it is not valid. I read you are meant to use and instead of nesting. Any ideas?

Comment: so so far what's the error ? is it working or the code is invalid with yours ?

Comment: It works yes but when I try validate it, it has errors and apparently you are not meant to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114000/nesting-media-queries

Answer (score 1):

Remember you are working with CASCADING style sheets!:) If you want your print query to override something you have in your media query just zero it out! for example:

```
@media screen {
  body {
   margin: 1px;
  }
}
@media print {
 body {
  margin: 0px;
  }
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Yes I understand this but then the print query will be huge, I am looking for a way to just ignore the screen query