# Combining logical OR and logical AND in the 'media' attribute for the <source> element

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to set up a `<picture>` element with several child `<source>` elements to serve images based on min-width and resolution conditions. I have 4 images:

- A wide 2x image (for retina devices with a min-width)
- A narrow 2x image (for retina devices under the min-width)
- A wide 1x image (for non-retina devices with a min-width)
- A narrow 1x image (for non-retina devices under the min-width)

Here's how I've put it all together:

```
<picture>
    <source
        srcset="Image_Wide_2x.jpeg"
        media="
            (min-width: 768px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
            (min-width: 768px) and (min-resolution: 192dpi)" >
    <source
        srcset="Image_Narrow_2x.jpeg"
        media="
            (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
            (min-resolution: 192dpi)" >
    <source
        srcset="Image_Wide_1x.jpeg"
        media="
            (min-width: 768px)" >
    <source
        srcset="Image_Narrow_1x.jpeg" >
    <img
        src=“someFallbackImage.jpeg” >
</picture>
```

This works as expected, but the repeaded min-width query on the first source element bugs me. I tried:

```
    <source
        srcset="ImageA@2x.jpeg"
        media="
            (min-width: 768px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi)" >
```

But that the browser interpreted that as... "If both the `min-width` and `webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` conditions are true, OR, just the `min-resolution` condition is true"

When what I wanted was... "If the `min-width` condition is true, and EITHER the `webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` or the `min-resolution` condition is true"

I read the documentation for the media attribute [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/), but it isn't very clear (to me, at least) what the order of operations are when combining the logical OR and logical AND operators.

FYI - I got the suggested retina queries from [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/) and [here](https://www.w3.org/blog/CSS/2012/06/14/unprefix-webkit-device-pixel-ratio/). I'm new to resolution queries, but I'm assuming I need both `webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` and `min-resolution`, and that's what's tripping me up.

Is there a better way to achieve what I want, using the picture and source elements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nesting Media Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114000/nesting-media-queries)

Comment: Nesting conditionals doesn't really work within media queries, you need to write out the entire statement each time in this case

Comment: @jmcgriz Just to confirm, when you say "you need to write out the entire statement each time in this case", you mean that the way I have it written is correct? Or are you referring to a different way of writing it?

Comment: Sorry, went on vacation - yes, the way you have it written is correct, there is no shorthand for combining media queries in the way that you'd like to.

Comment: @jmcgriz Thanks!